# Ubuntu doesn't give the correct keycodes for some media keys

Tags: sound, keyboard, 16.04, i3-wm, media-buttons

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my ThinkPad T450s and for some reason the media keys for volume and screen brightness are not giving any keycodes or keysyms (ie. XF86AudioRaiseVolume). But all the other media keys give the correct values.

What's weird is that the media keys still work fine in unity and gnome, it's just a problem when I use i3 because I can't map the volume keys to change the volume.

This is what `xev` returns for the volume down, volume up and volume mute keys:

Volume down:

```
FocusOut event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   


0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Volume Up:

```
FocusOut event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Volume mute:

```
FocusOut event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

As you can see, they are all the same. So I have no idea how unity or gnome can tell them apart. Just for reference I'll show the output for the mic off and wifi off media keys from `xev`:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0xf6, subw 0x0, time 3107820, (-19,759), root:(625,798),
    state 0x0, keycode 198 (keysym 0x1008ffb2, XF86AudioMicMute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0xf6, subw 0x0, time 3112189, (-19,759), root:(625,798),
    state 0x0, keycode 246 (keysym 0x1008ff95, XF86WLAN), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

And I used to get similar results for the volume keys before installing ubuntu as well (I was using Arch).

The brightness keys don't work either, are these being overridden at some low level? Is there a way I can fix it so they return the correct value or is there some other way I can get the media keys working for ubuntu?

**Update**: This is what `xev` gives for the volume up and down keys while I'm running unity.

```
FocusOut event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xf7, subw 0x0, time 2182026, (-1217,972), root:(525,2104),
    state 0x0, keycode 122 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xf7, subw 0x0, time 2185429, (-1217,972), root:(525,2104),
    state 0x0, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When running unity, I also have `unity-settings-daemon`, `unity-panel-service` and `unity-fallback-mount-helper`. Could one of these be catching the event and adding the `XF86` keysyms? None of these are running in i3.

In response to @Adaephon I have this in my i3 config:

```
# volume controls
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -q  set Master playback 2%+ unmute
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -q  set Master playback 2%- unmute
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer -q set Master mute
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the keys in question are already grabbed globally by some other application. The three segments of output you get from `xev` are only related to the xev window loosing and reaquireing the focus, while the key is grabbed otherwise (See [my post on the old *i3 FAQ*](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/4863/media-control-hotkeys-dont-work/index.html)).

There are two likely causes, why `xev` might show an output like that and the keybinding does not work:

1. First I would check, whether the keys in question - <kbd>XF86AudioLowerVolume</kbd> (keycode `122`), <kbd>XF86AudioRaiseVolume</kbd> (keycode `123`) and <kbd>XF86AudioMute</kbd> (keycode `121`) - are already bound with `bindsym` (or `bindcode`) in your *i3* configuration. Maybe it is only the bound command, which does not work.

   **(Update)** From the snippet of your *i3* config this seems to be the case. I think 16.04 uses PulseAudio by default, so `amixer` might not even be installed. You can use `pactl` to change the volume on PulseAudio. To emulate your previous `amixer` settings try this:

   ```
   bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +2%; exec pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ 0
   bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -2%; exec pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ 0
   bindsym XF86AudioMute exec pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle
   ```

   You can also use `1` instead of `toggle` on `set-sink-mute`, if you want to unmute only with the <kbd>XF86AudioLowerVolume</kbd> and <kbd>XF86AudioRaiseVolume</kbd> keys.
2. If that is not the case, some other tool is grabbing those keys. One likely candidate is `gnome-settings-daemon`, `unity-settings-daemon` might be another. Also, some media players may try to bind these keys globally. I suggest checking the output of `ps aux` on a fresh *i3* session to see what is automatically started. When you found the culprit you have essentially three options:

   - In most cases it should be possible to un-configure the key bindings. Probably the easiest solution, if you want to keep using whatever is grabbing the keys.
   - Make it work correctly. It may be that the program grabbing the key actually should do, what you want to do anyway (e.g. volume control), but for some reason it can not. For example: the program tries to change the volume with PulseAudio, while you are not actually using PulseAudio.
   - Stop it from starting. If you put it into autostart yourself (e.g. `exec` statement in your *i3* configuration), you can just remove it. If it is automatically started due to some Ubuntu preset, it may require more work.

---

For `gnome-settings-daemon` you can use the instructions from [my (other) post on the old *i3 FAQ*](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/5194/some-key-bindings-do-not-work-reliably-when-also-using-gnome-settings-daemon.1.html):

You should be able to get a list of bound keys with the following commands:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
```

You can then unset them by assinging an empy string

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute ''
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down ''
gesttings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up ''
```

Alternatively, you can also use `dconf`:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/volume-mute "''"
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/volume-down "''"
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/volume-up "''"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My i3 config has this in it:
```
# volume controls
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -q  set Master playback 2%+ unmute
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -q  set Master playback 2%- unmute
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer -q set Master mute
```

I ran `ps aux` straight after starting i3 and didn't find any settings daemon at all. I did find `gnome-keyring-daemon`, `gnome-screensaver`, `avahi-daeman` and a couple of others that don't look suspicious though.

Comment: I've updated my question to give more info too.

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me So it is indeed *i3* itself which is grabbing the keys. If you still can not change the volume, it is likely that the command itself does not work. Did you try running them in a terminal (e.g. `amixer -q  set Master playback 2%+ unmute`)? I think 16.04 uses PulseAudio by default, so `amixer` might not even be installed.  You can use `pactl` to change the volume on PulseAudio: `pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +2%`, `pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle` (or use `0` or `1` instead of `toggle` to disable or enable mute, respectively).

Comment: I added the bit about `pactl` to the answer. I left the rest unchanged as it may be of help to others finding your question due to similar but not identical issues.

Comment: 20.04 LTS upgrade fallout saw the default /bin/sh link reverted to dash, thus bashisms in a custom bound script (#!/bin/sh) were silently failing. So "no", nothing changed with kernel modules / firmware, my ThinkPad WAS still generating the XF86* keysyms without the need for the addition 'Shift' modifier! removal of the binding in the i3 config eventually showed me that I'd been well and truly barking up the wrong tree. I'd always thought xev (testing) worked at a lower level than 'unprivileged ui client only capable of picking up on whatever's leftover / unbound', nope! thanks @Adaephon