# Why does the Fn key lower brightness on my Ubuntu? (Magic Keyboard)

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to understand what is going on. I'm running `xev` to debug this issue.

For a normal key, like `ESC`, the output of `xev` is:

```bash
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    root 0x7c0, subw 0x0, time 5520877, (82,81), root:(3374,285),
    state 0x10, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
```

But with Fn, the result is:

```bash
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967232 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I wanted to remap the key using the `xkb` file, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161870/1092737), but it's not evident how to do for the Fn.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the key was being captured by another application, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/770101/1092737), namely, `gnome-settings-daemon`.

I installed `sudo apt install dconf-editor`, and then I could change the binding of the key:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/screen-brightness-down-static
```

and I set it to `''`. After restarting the computer, the key did not change my screen brightness anymore, and the output of `xev` for the key is:

```bash
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x7c0, subw 0x0, time 27282496, (170,174), root:(3443,1424),
    state 0x10, keycode 232 (keysym 0x1008ff03, XF86MonBrightnessDown), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```